# precision_recall_fscore_support return the same value precision recall

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I am using `precision_recall_fscore_support` from `sklearn` to calculate the micro-precision, and micro-recall.

The problem is that the function returns the exact same value for both of them. It is a multi-class classification problem and I am not sure what went wrong.

Here is the code:

```
t = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, classifier.predict(x_test), average='micro')
print(t)
```

Here is the output:

> Micro accuracy:  (0.3359375, 0.3359375, 0.3359375, None)

Comment: It's likely not a problem with the function but the predictions. How man values are there, can you include them in the post?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your name, but if you're asking about how many samples then there are 128.

Comment: Please show the complete data of y_test and the output of `classifier.predict(x_test)`.

Comment: Please tell us more about the data that you are working with. Also, get the result from `classification_report` and add it to the question so we know the scores for each of your class without considering the average

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you expecting to see?  In section 3.3.2.8.2. of the documentation, [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html),  it states  “micro”-averaging in a multiclass setting with all labels included will produce equal precision, recall and F", and suggests you should try `average = "weighted"`.

[Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5710) is a similar complaint on Scikit-learn's Github.